# How do I get Ionide to see .net core Linq and AspNetCore namespaces?

Tags: linq, f#, ionide

I recently installed dotnet core 1.0.0-rc4-004771. After generating a new fsharp project with the following command: "dotnet new mvc -lang f#"
Ionide complains that it can't find the Linq and AspNetCore namespaces even though "dotnet build" builds just fine.

[image]

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: what platform are you on? for instance on mac ionide still works with mono-based f# afaik, not with .net code one

Comment: I see this behavior on both OSX as well ubuntu 16.04. Looks like your right, looks like they are still working on it. https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/366 My mistake :(

Comment: I see this a lot in linux.  Restarting Code is the only fix I've found.

Comment: Yeah, restarting doesn't help. In looking at the source code for fsautocomplete, it looks like there changes made to support .net core. Even for the latest version that supports fsproj instead of project.json https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete/blob/master/src/FsAutoComplete.Core/Commands.fs (line 104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be fixed now, with

- ionide >= 2.25.1
- .net core sdk rtm (1.0.1)

see https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/wiki/.NET-Core-SDK-1.0.1 for more info

```
dotnet new mvc -lang f#
dotnet restore
code .
```

restore can be done after open code too, but is required to make intellisense work